# How to access 'parent' from BeautifulSoup using select or find?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# raw = requests.get("https://www.daum.net")
# raw = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/emp")

response = requests.get("https://vip.mk.co.kr/newSt/rate/item_all.php?koskok=KOSPI&orderBy=upjong")
response.raise_for_status()
response.encoding= 'EUC-KR'
html = response.text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

result = bs.select("tr .st2")

    <tr>
      <td width='92' class='st2'><a href="javascript:goPrice('000020&MSid=&msPortfolioID=')" title='000020'>somethinbg</a></td>
      <td width='60' align='right'>15,100</td>
      <td width='40' align='right'><span class='t_12_blue'>▼300</span></td>
    </tr>
```

I want to get datas from the someweher by using BeautifulSoup.
But I should access parent Node where has .
However, it's really hard to do it.

This is the code:

Then, how can I get datas from the parent which has the '<tr class ='st2>''

here is the example

Comment: What do you want to scrape from that HTML ? Can you elaborate with an example ?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent element in BeautifulSoup via the element's `parent` attribute. Since you asked for a list of elements, this has to be done in an iteration.
I'm assuming here that you want to extract each row in the table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://vip.mk.co.kr/newSt/rate/item_all.php?koskok=KOSPI&orderBy=upjong")
response.raise_for_status()
response.encoding= 'EUC-KR'
html = response.text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

result = [[child.text for child in elem.parent.findChildren('td', recursive=False)] \
    for elem in bs.select('tr .st2')]
```

The result is:

```
[
   ['동화약품', '15,100', '▼300'], 
   ['유한양행', '61,100', '▼400'], 
   ['유한양행우', '58,900', '▲300'],
   ...
]
```